# Errors in designing Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have been following a tutorial on Android design and decided to write the UI layout for a Navigation Drawer.
In my `activity_main.xml` file, i wrote this -

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"

  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

  <FrameLayout

      android:id="@+id/frame_container"

      android:layout_width="match_parent"

      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

  <ListView

      android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"

      android:layout_width="240dp"

      android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_gravity="start"

      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

      android:divider="@color/list_divider"

      android:dividerHeight="1dp"     

      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

      android:background="@color/list_background"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But i keep getting an error saying -

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'divider' with value '@color/  list_divider').

and

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value '@color/  list_background').

Please how do i fix this? What could be the problem? Do i need a third-party library to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: do you have  resource by name list_background in `colors.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

In color.xml file

```
<color name="list_divider">#000000</color>
<color name="list_background">#3D3B3B</color>
```